# Ambiguous use of filter when getting frequency count of characters in a string

Tags: ios, swift

I implemented a function to calculate the hamming distance using Swift, it uses the xor operation x ^ y to get the different bits. Then, I convert the result from an Int to a String of 8 characters which is the 8 bit representation of my Xor. However, I am getting the error:

**Compile Error: ambiguous use of 'filter'**

```
class Solution {
    func hammingDistance(_ x: Int, _ y: Int) -> Int {
        let xor = x ^ y //xor: compares bits 
        let xorBinary = String(xor, radix: 2)
        let xor8BitBinaryStr = String(repeating: Character("0"), count: 8 - xorBinary.count) + xorBinary

        return xor8BitBinaryStr.filter({ $0 == "1" }).count
    }
}

let c = Solution()
print(c.hammingDistance(1, 4)) //prints 2
```

Comment: The code compiles without error or warning in Swift 4.1. Which version of Swift are you using?

Answer (score 1):

You can filter like this to avoid confusion for the compiler,

```
let items = xor8BitBinaryStr.filter({ $0 == "1"})
return items.count
```

OR

```
return Array(xor8BitBinaryStr).filter({ $0 == "1" }).count
```

Answer (score 0):

To solve this, declare the **type** of the `xor8BitBinaryStr` before you perform operations on it.

```
let xor8BitBinaryStr : `data type here` = String(repeating: Character("0"), count: 8 - xorBinary.count) + xorBinary
```

Comment: The type is clearly `String` and the compiler knows that.

Answer (score 0):

In Swift 4.0, there are two `filter` methods on `String` which only differ by their return type.

One returns `String`, the other `[Character]`.

If you don't explicitly declare the type of the return you expect, it defaults to `String`.

Therefore, if you want to get `[Character]`, you need to do something like this:

```
let chars: [Character] = xor8BitBinaryStr.filter({ $0 == "1" })
return chars.count
```

EDIT: This was a bug in Swift that was fixed, presumably in 4.1. It was marked Resolved on 11/17/17. See https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-5175?jql=text%20~%20%22filter%22